# Help understanding oblique asymptotes for $f(x) = 2x^3+3x^2-12x$

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm having some difficulty understanding oblique asymptotes.

Let's have

$$f(x) = 2x^3+3x^2-12x$$

The oblique asymptote appears only when

$$\lim_{x\to \pm \infty} f(x) = \pm \infty$$

---

So I need to evaluate two limits.

$$\lim_{x\to + \infty} f(x) = +\infty$$

and

$$\lim_{x\to - \infty} f(x) = -\infty$$

---

Ok good, it seems we got two oblique asymptotes? One to the right and another to the left?

Let's focus on the one to the right. The slope is

$$m = \lim_{x\to +\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}$$

Evaluating yields that $m = \infty$.

....... this can't be right. An infinite slope would be a straight vertical line.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are wrongly interpreting the result. $x^3$ has an oblique asymptote *and* it's slope tends to infinity. No contradiction here.